# Translation of "Great!"

Tags: traducción, adjetivos, adverbios, interjecciones

In English, the interjection "Great!" can be used to respond to almost any statement. In Spanish, I've heard a few similar interjections:

- ¡Qué bien!
- ¡Qué bueno!
- ¡Está bien!
- ¡Está bueno!

I've always had a hard time understanding the difference between these and when they're used. What are the options for translating "Great!", and how are they used?

Answer (score 3):

This translation will depend not only on the country or region you're speaking Spanish, but will also depend on the age the people you are talking to.

For example, in Chile (and I think in many other places as well) we can say with a "neutral dialect":

- ¡Genial!
- ¡Excelente!

But according to the age of the people who were talking, you could hear also in Chile:

- ¡Bacán!  (a word from the nineties)
- ¡Groso!  (a word from the eighties)
- ¡La raja!  (a very informal way)

Comment: *Joya*, *masa*, *bárbaro*, *buenísimo* and *copado* are commonly used in informal every-day speech in Argentina. *Bárbaro* and *buenísimo*, however, are a little more formal/safer to use than the others.